# You need rest vs You need a rest

Tags: word-choice, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Literally as above, I encountered those sentences in my reading. 
I wonder about difference between them.

Is 'You need a rest' a more emphatic suggestion than 'You need rest' in spoken English? As I read those sentences in the book it sounds almost no difference in a general meaning.

is there any difference in nuances (or nuance?) between them?
[nuances vs nuance is complicated for me as well.]

Comment: 'You need rest' is rather unusual; you'd expect it from a doctor about to give you a few days off work. It's in a rather formal register. // 'You need a rest' would typically be said to a colleague / friend / family member who needed to take an hour's break say (though it could also be used if the few days off was considered appropriate). It's far more conversational in tone. Both are non-count usages (*'You need two rests'), though 'a rest' has more of a 'fixed unit' feel about it. 'Rest' also means 'inactivity' so 'You need rest' parallels 'You need [more] sleep'.

Comment: A little bit confusing...I understand it this way 'a rest' is more realistic and direct. then it can be applied depending on the situation...in this sense 'You need rest' can be unusual because it can sound too indirect. if there is a patient, then a friend of the patient say 'you need rest' and then it can be a kind of mild suggestion?  or ' you need a rest'  and then it can be a strong suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I'd say "You need rest" is a notch or two higher on the chivvying scale than "You need a rest" and certainly than "You could do with a rest"; "You could do with rest" sounds incongruous, mismatched.

Comment: I think it's similar to this example. 'There is a little water in the bottle' and 'There is little water in the bottle'. when the speaker is negative, then can say there is little water and when positive, then can say there is a little water. In my opinion your answers and the other answer below will be both available..

Comment: No, that's an incorrect comparison. 'I need coffee!' and 'I need a coffee!' is an example of the same form as the original, but here, there is very little difference at all in meaning. The former is just in a slightly more quirky vein. _Beware claiming correspondence on the grounds of analogy in English._

Comment: "I need a coffee" is a very common shortening of "I need a [cup of] coffee." In the UK they shorten it somewhat differently as "I need a cuppa [tea]"

"I need coffee" may have the same effect, but the meaning is more, "I need some coffee in my system, now, before I fall asleep."

"I need coffee" is often the first sentence someone says when they wake up in the morning. They don't really care whether it comes in a cup or a bottle at that point.

Comment: above is an example which i found online. further I mean the amount of water in the bottle is same in any case. the speaker's attitude is different only. coffee example is consistent to water example. be aware of it

Comment: You're wrong in not realising that 'little' and 'a little' are quantifiers with very different implications, and are very different usages from the zero and indefinite articles before a noun (I fancy currry / a curry for tea). 'There is little time left' is a warning to make haste, whereas 'there is a little time left' means we needn't be precipitate. // Isn't '[B]e aware of it' patronising? The overall standard of the English in our various comments warrants scrutiny. As does the number of downvotes on your accepted answer.

Comment: 'Beware claiming correspondence on the grounds of analogy in English.' i dont understand this. once again coffee example is consistent to water example. Truth is not complicated at all. sometimes it's not that easy to realize it though

Comment: So you're a more able linguist than the person who wrote 'nuances vs nuance is complicated for me as well'?

Comment: alright..first answer quite helpful for me to understand concepts of noun in English. i appreciated it. abstract noun like nuance is not clear to understand how to use it in the sentence. i think nuance, abstract noun, should be used as mass noun.. but referring to dictionary it is used as countable noun.'is there any difference in nuances' will be correct. is it right?

Comment: I think you're trying to run before you can walk. The general standard of English in your comments shows that ELL would be a more appropriate site, though your question certainly addresses a complex issue. Articles (in the other sense) are still being written exploring the use of articles in English, and Collins have a 100+ page monograph devoted to them (and it's far from comprehensive). 'You need rest' and 'you need a rest' are subtly different but both idiomatic. 'Is there any difference in nuance?' (not nuances) and 'Are there different nuances?' both work and are very similar in meaning.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need rest determine that some is casually telling you take rest but the other You need a rest simplifies that now you have to take and generally he/she felling care for you[.](https://www.mykfcexperience.us/)

Comment: The answer is garbled and misspelt. Please think about joining our sister-site [ell.se].